# Are there issues mounting file shares on azure in a different data center?

Tags: azure

When I try to mount a file share in Linux VM, I use the following command:

```
mount -t cifs <file-share> /tffs -o vers=3.0,username=<username>,password=<key>,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

The file share is in Central US.  When I run this command on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine in Central US, it works fine.

When I run it on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine in South Central US, I get this:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

dmesg gives me this:

```
[  156.010050] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
[  156.013201] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

Has anyone experienced this before?  How do I get around this problem?

Comment: As far as I know, we can't mount file share to the VM which in another region.

Answer (score 1):

Note the documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) which says:

> Note
>
> The Linux SMB client doesn’t yet support encryption, so mounting a
>   file share from Linux still requires that the client be in the same
>   Azure region as the file share. However, encryption support for Linux
>   is on the roadmap of Linux developers responsible for SMB
>   functionality. Linux distributions that support encryption in the
>   future will be able to mount an Azure File share from anywhere as
>   well.

Edit: There has been an update on Ububtu [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/azure-file-storage-on-premises-access-for-ubuntu/).